# embedded web server to run php

Tags: php, embeddedwebserver

im looking for embedded web server that can parse php 
do you have experience with such ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think Appweb can do this.

http://www.appwebserver.org/

More info:

http://www.appwebserver.org/products/appweb/doc.2/guide/appweb/users/php.html

Comment: looking for lgpl stuff so i can use it on none open source